# How can I reindex elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, jhipster

I am using `jhipster 7.5.0` and I tryed to install `generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer`, but seems it does not work with this `jhipster` version. I am trying to `reindex` all `elasticsearch` indexes manually, but I do not know how can I do that.

Comment: do you want to reindex data from existing index or actual data source ? which versin of ES you are using ?

Comment: I want to recreate all the existent index from the actual database, because I added data by out of ES. I m using ES 7.9.3

Comment: Have a look into the following generator [jhipster-es-entity-reindexer][1], this  looks more recent than `generator-jhipster-elasticsearch-reindexer`.


  [1]: https://github.com/Ebsan/generator-jhipster-es-entity-reindexer